# multiple h:forms in ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm trying to have multiple h:forms on a page which are rendered with a ui:repeat component. If I have only one generated h:form, everything works perfect. If I have multiple h:forms, only the latest h:form will work! (If I try to submit another form then the last, only null is passed trough my service!)

```
<ui:repeat var="element" value="#{myService.elementList}">



            <rich:simpleTogglePanel switchType="client"
                                    label="#{element.codeElement} - #{element.description}" 
                                    opened="#{myService.isUiSelected(element)}"
                                    onexpand="expand#{element.codeElement}()"
                                    oncollapse="collapse#{element.codeElement}()">



    <h:form id="newKindForm">
      <a:commandLink ajaxSingle="true" id="idLink" onclick="#{rich:component('newTargetPanel')}.show()">
       <a:commandButton id="myButton" 
                        value="new Form"
                    action="#{myService.newForm(element)}"/> 
       </a:commandLink>                
    </h:form>


    <rich:modalPanel id="newTargetPanel" autosized="true" width="450">
       <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="My Pannel Title" />
       </f:facet>
       <f:facet name="controls">
          <h:panelGroup>
             <h:graphicImage value="/img/close.png" 
                             id="hidelink"
                             styleClass="hidelink" />
                <rich:componentControl for="newTargetPanel" 
                                       attachTo="hidelink"
                                       operation="hide" 
                                       event="onclick" />
          </h:panelGroup>
       </f:facet>



<!-- THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC FORM -->
<h:form>
     <a:include viewId="../myRepeatableForm.xhtml" />
</h:form>



</rich:modalPanel>



</ui:repeat>
```

Some suggestion?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

you can contain everything in a single form, and use `execute` attribute to submit only the elements you want. like this:

`<h:form id="newKindForm" prependId="false">
    <ui:repeat id="newKindRepeat" var="element"
        value="#{myService.elementList}" varStatus="varStatus">
        <h:panelGroup id="newKindPanel">
           <a:commandButton id="myButton"
              execute="newKindRepeat:#{varStatus.index}:newKindPanel"
              onclick="#{rich:component('newTargetPanel')}.show()"
              value="new Form"
              action="#{myService.newForm(element)}"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </ui:repeat>
</h:form>`

please notice `prependId` of `h:form`, `id` and `varStatus` of `ui:repeat`, `execute` of `a:commandButton`.

btw, supposing that `a:` stands for ajax4jsf, i wouldn't recommend using commandButton nested in commandLink.

Comment: in this case, how does the controller know which instance of the form to choose from the collection?  IOW, if the `ui:repeat` has 7 iterations and each iteration's fields are named the same (IOW are not indexed), doesn't that introduce ambiguity?

Comment: @amphibient what do you mean by "named"? if you mean ids, yes, they should be unique dom-wide, and they are. when you open up the html source after the above code is rendered, you'll see spans (h:panelGroup) with ids `newKingRepeat:0:newKindPanel`, `newKingRepeat:1:newKindPanel`, `newKingRepeat:2:newKindPanel` and so on... `ui:repeat` prepends it's own id and current index to the component ids nested in it. `execute="newKingRepeat:#{varStatus.index}:newKindPanel"` part decides which span content will be submitted to the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Is #{myService.elementList} a List ? If so, I'm not sure if that will work. Try using javax.faces.model.DataModel instead. Be sure to read the documentation carefully. It works something like this:

```
public Datamodel getElements(){
  if(elements == null)
      elements = new ListDataModel(getElementList()); 
    return elements;
}

public List<Element> getElementList(){
    elementList = foo(); // load the elements in your List like you did before
    return elementList;
}
```

in your view: `<ui:repeat var="element" value="#{myService.elements}">`

I'm not familiar with RichFaces, this is the only suggestion I can make.

Comment: it should work just fine with a list. using Datamodel is not mandatory.